# Please identify this game - 4x4 diagonal squares, 4 red and 4 blue pieces - nice wooden board

Tags: identify-this-game

[image]Can anyone please tell me what this game is called AND /OR how to play it?
Many thanks

Answer (score 8):

I believe the game your looking for is [Oska](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/19495/oska).

[image: Image Of Oska]

I found it by typing various descriptions into Google image search and found a similar looking games called 'queah'  then came across Oska whilst trying to find similar games to that.

Comment: Hi there Mr StartPlayer: Thank you so much for your help - I’ll enjoy playing it now I have an idea of what to do.

Comment: I found another website really useful https://tametheboardgame.com/2014/01/20/oska/comment-page-1/#comment-3089